# Show a complex number is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree at most 80

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $p(a)=0$ where $$p(x) = x^5+\sqrt{2}x^3+\sqrt{5}x^2+\sqrt{7} x + \sqrt{11}$$

Then show $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree at most 80.

Clearly $a$ is a root of an equation with irrational coefficients.

Completely stumped on this one. I was trying with field extensions: $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}):\mathbb{Q}]\leq [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}):\mathbb{Q}][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}):\mathbb{Q}]$$

But don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It has degree $\le5 $ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt5,\sqrt7,\sqrt{11})$.

Comment: Two good answers, both posted as comments...

Comment: Moved mine to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality of field extension degrees is fine (assuming you meant $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt5, \sqrt7,\sqrt{11})$ when you wrote $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)\Bbb Q(\sqrt7)\Bbb Q(\sqrt{11})$). The product on the right-hand side is $16$, and that's all you need.

If $t$ is a root in your polynomial, note that since $t$ is a root of a degree $5$ polynomial, we get
$$
[\Bbb Q(t,\sqrt2, \sqrt5, \sqrt7,\sqrt{11}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt5, \sqrt7,\sqrt{11})]\leq5
$$
Combine this with your inequality, and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Well, we are sure that if we take the given polynomial and multiply it by

$x^5+\sqrt{2}x^3+\sqrt{5}x^2+\sqrt{7}x−\sqrt{11}$,

then

$x^5+\sqrt{2}x^3+\sqrt{5}x^2-\sqrt{7}x+\sqrt{11}$,

and so on through all the sign combinations of square roots, the radicals will surely be cancelled out by the symmetry of the product. Thus $x$ solves the product polynomial with rational coefficients only, and degree $5×16=80$.